# find unused properties in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, resourcebundle

I have set of classes and (struts)jsp files which uses Message bundle. I want to find properties which are not used in project.One simple way would to search for each property (in given project) and if 0 result, delete it.

In eclipse there is a function like

Source > Find Broken Externalized Strings

I don't think it works. Not sure what its for. I get message

"no nls property files with corresponding accessor of class found in selection"

Comment: The error message is actually "No NLS property files with corresponding accessor class found in selection"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Eclipse expects to find the class that it generates in the "Externalize Strings..." command:

```
package com.foo.bar;

import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Messages {
    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "com.foo.bar.messages"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private static final ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

    private Messages() {
    }

    public static String getString(String key) {
        try {
            return RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return '!' + key + '!';
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, after digging a little deeper, I found that Eclipse really wants the following:

```
private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "com.foo.bar.messages"; //$NON-NLS-1$

public static String getString(String key) {
    ...
}
```

The package "com.foo.bar" must contain the file "messages.properties". You can run "Find Broken Externalized Strings" on any source file (or on the package) that you add these lines to.